# Firebase cloud function import FireStore error

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing cloud function and Firestore is imported automatically like so.

```
 import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
 import { QuerySnapshot } from '@google-cloud/firestore';
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const membersSnapshot: QuerySnapshot = await admin.firestore.doc('team/' + groupId + '/members').get()
```

But when deploying this, error says below.
I tried like this and it deployed without any error but I'm not sure this is correct way or not.

```
const membersSnapshot: Array<functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot> = await admin.firestore.doc('team/' + groupId + '/members').get()
```

Does anyone have any idea?

> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:28:15 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'DocumentData'.
>
> 28   export type DocumentData = {[field: string]: any};
>                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:35:15 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'UpdateData'.
>
> 35   export type UpdateData = {[fieldPath: string]: any};
>                    ~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:86:16 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Firestore'.
>
> 86   export class Firestore {
>                     ~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:176:16 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'GeoPoint'.
>
> 176   export class GeoPoint {
>                      ~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:203:16 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Transaction'.
>
> 203   export class Transaction {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:320:16 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'WriteBatch'.
>
> 320   export class WriteBatch {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:414:14 -
>   error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same
>   type.  Property 'lastUpdateTime' must be of type 'string', but here
>   has type 'Timestamp'.
>
> 414     readonly lastUpdateTime?: Timestamp;
>                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:446:16 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'WriteResult'.
>
> 446   export class WriteResult {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:469:16 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'DocumentReference'.
>
> 469   export class DocumentReference {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:609:16 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'DocumentSnapshot'.
>
> 609   export class DocumentSnapshot {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:678:16 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'.
>
> 678   export class QueryDocumentSnapshot extends DocumentSnapshot {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:705:15 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'OrderByDirection'.
>
> 705   export type OrderByDirection = 'desc' | 'asc';
>                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:711:15 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'WhereFilterOp'.
>
> 711   export type WhereFilterOp = '<' | '<=' | '==' | '>=' | '>' |
>   'array-contains';
>                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:717:16 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Query'.
>
> 717   export class Query {
>                      ~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:925:16 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'QuerySnapshot'.
>
> 925   export class QuerySnapshot {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:977:15 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'DocumentChangeType'.
>
> 977   export type DocumentChangeType = 'added' | 'removed' |
>   'modified';
>                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:1020:16 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CollectionReference'.
>
> 1020   export class CollectionReference extends Query {
>                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:1071:16 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FieldValue'.
>
> 1071   export class FieldValue {
>                       ~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:1132:16 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FieldPath'.
>
> 1132   export class FieldPath {
>                       ~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:1243:12 -
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FirebaseFirestore'.
>
> 1243   export = FirebaseFirestore;
>                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:28:15 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'DocumentData'.
>
> 28   export type DocumentData = {[field: string]: any};
>                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:35:15 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'UpdateData'.
>
> 35   export type UpdateData = {[fieldPath: string]: any};
>                    ~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:46:16 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Firestore'.
>
> 46   export class Firestore {
>                     ~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:122:16
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'GeoPoint'.
>
> 122   export class GeoPoint {
>                      ~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:149:16
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Transaction'.
>
> 149   export class Transaction {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:266:16
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'WriteBatch'.
>
> 266   export class WriteBatch {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:393:16
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'WriteResult'.
>
> 393   export class WriteResult {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:417:16
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'DocumentReference'.
>
> 417   export class DocumentReference {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:557:16
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'DocumentSnapshot'.
>
> 557   export class DocumentSnapshot {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:626:16
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'.
>
> 626   export class QueryDocumentSnapshot extends DocumentSnapshot {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:653:15
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'OrderByDirection'.
>
> 653   export type OrderByDirection = 'desc' | 'asc';
>                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:659:15
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'WhereFilterOp'.
>
> 659   export type WhereFilterOp = '<' | '<=' | '==' | '>=' | '>';
>                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:665:16
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Query'.
>
> 665   export class Query {
>                      ~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:873:16
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'QuerySnapshot'.
>
> 873   export class QuerySnapshot {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:925:15
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'DocumentChangeType'.
>
> 925   export type DocumentChangeType = 'added' | 'removed' |
>   'modified';
>                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:968:16
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CollectionReference'.
>
> 968   export class CollectionReference extends Query {
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:1019:16
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FieldValue'.
>
> 1019   export class FieldValue {
>                       ~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:1047:16
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FieldPath'.
>
> 1047   export class FieldPath {
>                       ~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:1073:12
>   - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FirebaseFirestore'.
>
> 1073   export = FirebaseFirestore;
>                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" this issue by downgrading my firestore-admin version. It used to be

```
"firebase-admin": "6.0.1"
```

and is now

```
"firebase-admin": "6.0.0"
```

Of course this is no long term solution to this issue, but will get you going for once.